# How to calculate the accuracy_score leaving out one class?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

My classifier: Random Forest

My labels: 6 labels and one label for data objects that does not belong to any of the 6 labels

When calling the method `accuracy_score`, the accuracy for 7 labels is calculated. But since the accuracy of the 6 'real' labels is important for me, I want their accuracy.

(It does not help to leave out the 7th label in the training data because I am comparing the accuracies after doing something with the 7th label.)

Code:
`print(accuracy_score(y, y_pred))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do instead :

```py
# outClass : the class you want to leave out
condition = (y != outClass)
score = (y[condition] == y_pred[condition]).sum()/ (y[condition]).size
```